# SAS check field by field

Tags: arrays, sas, datastep

I try build little check process. One `proc sql` generated one row table (and 13 fields) and next step I need check that chosen field in the table has `value <> 0`. 
Below my current (not completed) code with example table `"have"`:

```
data Have;
   input REFERENCE_DATE  
         L_CONTRACT 
         L_CONTRACT_ACTIVITY
         L_LFC
         L_CONTRACT_CO_CUSTOMER
         L_CONTRACT_OBJECT
         L_CUSTOMER
         L_CUSTOMER_RETAIL
         L_DPD
         L_GL_ACCOUNT 
         L_GL_AMOUNT
         L_EXTRA_COST 
         L_PRODUCT;
   datalines;
450 1 9 8 6 0 4 3 0 0 0 0 0
;

Data work.Collect_data2;
    set work.have;
ARRAY tab(13) _temporary_ (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) ;
ARRAY tab_check(*) L_CONTRACT-L_CUSTOMER_RETAIL;
input id L_CONTRACT-L_CUSTOMER_RETAIL;

do j= 2 to 7;

end;

run;
```

I need to check field by field since L_CONTRACT to L_CUSTOMER_RETAIL (field 2 to 7).
If anyfield from this pieces has value = 0 - I need return info that something is not ok.
Thanks for help!

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
length flag $10.;
if whichn(0, of L_contract -- l_customer_retail) then flag='Not Ok';
else flag='Ok';
```

You can use the `WHICHN()` function to test if any value is 0 in a series of variables. No array declarations needed.  I'm confused as to why you have an `INPUT` statement along with a `SET` statement but no `INFILE` or 'CARDS` though.  That doesn't make sense to me.

Edit: change single dash to two dashes.

Comment: Hey Reeza. Thanks for the solution. I do not know function WHICHN. In this case that procedure doesn't work (SAS show me error: Alphabetic prefixes for enumerated variables (L_contract-l_customer_retail) are different.) but I did rebuild your code like as:

`length flag $10.;
if whichn(0, of L_:) then flag='Not Ok';
else flag='Ok';`

Before, I got fields which I want check. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that should be two dashes, I blame autocorrect ;)

Comment: O, strange. I added once two dashes and it didn't work, but now works..
Big thx Reeza :) Your solution opening more new possibility :)