# SAS check field by field and put field name when 0

Tags: sas

My question is related with below topic:
[SAS check field by field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954188/sas-check-field-by-field).
I'm searching method which set (put) to string/variable name of columns if field has value of 0.
Is there an elegant method for the?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VNAME` function will return the name of the variable corresponding to an array reference.

```
data Have;
   input REFERENCE_DATE  
         L_CONTRACT 
         L_CONTRACT_ACTIVITY
         L_LFC
         L_CONTRACT_CO_CUSTOMER
         L_CONTRACT_OBJECT
         L_CUSTOMER
         L_CUSTOMER_RETAIL
         L_DPD
         L_GL_ACCOUNT 
         L_GL_AMOUNT
         L_EXTRA_COST 
         L_PRODUCT;
   datalines;
450 1 9 8 6 0 4 3 0 0 0 0 0
;

data want;
  length vars_with_zero $1000;
  set have;
  array L L_CONTRACT -- L_CUSTOMER_RETAIL;

  * accumulate the names of the variables that have a zero value;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(L);
    if L(_n_) = 0 then vars_with_zero = catx(' ', vars_with_zero, vname(L(_n_)));
  end;
run;
```