# SAS check field by column by column

Tags: sas

[SAS check field by field and put field name when 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54588071/sas-check-field-by-field-and-put-field-name-when-0)

I have new little problem. I want checking field by field whether values are the same. Row by row. And excellent if code will insert new row with status 'OK' and "NOT OK'.

```
data Have;
   input REFERENCE_DATE  
         L_CONTRACT 
         L_CONTRACT_ACTIVITY
         L_LFC
         L_CONTRACT_CO_CUSTOMER
         L_CONTRACT_OBJECT
         L_CUSTOMER
         L_CUSTOMER_RETAIL
         L_DPD
         L_GL_ACCOUNT 
         L_GL_AMOUNT
         L_EXTRA_COST 
         L_PRODUCT;
   datalines;
450 1 9 8 6 0 4 3 0 0 0 0 0
450 1 8 8 5 5 3 3 0 0 0 0 1
;
```

I created little code that compare this - but I have problem - in first record put all columns as error... I need put only for second record in the variables field - which columns has different value.

```
Data Have_to;
length variables $1000;
    set Have;
    array L L_CONTRACT -- L_PRODUCT;
        DO _n_ = 1 to dim(L);
            IF L(_n_) ne lag1(L(_n_)) THEN variables = catx(' ', variables, vname(L(_n_)));
        END;
run;
```

And how I can create new table where I would have only columns where code calculate the differences? (in the example: L_CONTRACT_ACTIVITY L_CONTRACT_CO_CUSTOMER L_CONTRACT_OBJECT L_CUSTOMER L_PRODUCT).

Best regards and thank you

Comment: Is this a report ? Describe the process you would do to get the 'status row' values. What have your tried ? Do you know about ARRAY and LAG ?  If a column is numeric, you won't be able to have a status row with character values.  If rows are 1,2,3,4 do you want output 1,2,status(1:2),3,4,status(3:4) or 1,2,status(1:2),3,status(2:3),4,status(3:4) ?  Update the question with more information, don't put more info in comments.

Comment: Hey Richard - idea with array is good, but I have little problem - i set this in my question.

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel for this - read up on proc compare:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1f136xdchlfrtn1663tmzklctb6.htm